# Include two document roots in Apache?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have http://example.com/pic1.jpg, pic2.jpg, pic3.jpg, and so on for hundreds of jpgs, on my original server, but I need to move it to http://example.com/pictures/pic[##].jpg. Many different servers and pages link to these pictures, so if at all possible, I don't want to just move the pictures and change the links. Is it possible to include another directory as a second document root in Apache?

So, even though the picture is actually located at /pictures/pic1.jpg, linking to just /pic1.jpg will work fine too?

Edit: I don't want to symlink because of the clutter from having so many pictures in the root.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a .htaccess file in root directory to redirect all requests to pictures directory when there is no file in root with that name.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /pictures/$1 [L]
```

An about main question. No it is not possible to have two document root (Not acceptable from logical point of view too). But you can redirect requests using .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

In my httpd.conf file, for the document root, I have the following block now:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+) http://example.com/pictures%{REQUEST_URI}
</Directory>
```

So, if you try to go to http://example.com/pic1.jpg and it doesn't exist, it will then redirect you to http://example.com/pictures/pic1.jpg. This could be made better, like only doing it when REQUEST_URL contains .jpg, but it works for me for now.